# Decode the json array and break with foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to decode json and then break the value with foreach loop.
Here is my script.

```
 <?php $new_data=json_decode($pay_data->l1_level,true);
                      print_r($new_data);
                     ?>
```

this print return array.

```
Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => sanjay [1] => susanchen [2] => mabelzhen) [product-price] => Array ( [0] => 250 [1] => 250 [2] => 250) )
```

I am trying to break this foreach loop and get name and price value . I am trying to this away

```
foreach($new_data as $value){
echo $value->name;
echo $value->product_price ;
}
```

But This is not working.Any Help will be Appreciate.

Comment: it's inside another dimension, so if you want to reach out `name`, you'd need to directly point to it `foreach ($new_data['name'] as $v)`, and same for the price. if you need to iterate on the whole thing, just add another foreach inside `foreach ($new_data as $value) { foreach ($value as $v) }` like so

Comment: Kevin , I can not irritate whole thing . I have to put these thing in  html table so I am breking this key and value. please help to get this as key and value

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

Comment: You're mixing up array and object access. See the proposed duplicate for examples on how to handle either.

Answer (score 0):

When you use foreach($new_data as $value), the $value doesn't have the key.

Please try the following code.

```
    foreach($new_data as $value){
        print_r($value);
    }
```

the result is
Array ( [0] => sanjay [1] => susanchen [2] => mabelzhen ) Array ( [0] => 250 [1] => 250 [2] => 250 )

Comment: Wizard@ Hey I  need this value to put in  <td>echo $value->name</td>. please let me know how can  list the all value in coulumn

Comment: In PHP,  ->, is used in object scope to access methods and properties of an object. It’s meaning is to say that what is on the right of the operator is a member of the object instantiated into the variable on the left side of the operator. Instantiated is the key term here. 
// Create a new instance of MyObject into $obj
$obj = new MyObject();
// Set a property in the $obj object called thisProperty
$obj->thisProperty = 'Fred';

Comment: $new_data is an Array. So print_r( $new_data["name"]); will show the "name" array.

Comment: wizard then how can  get  object data of this  $new_data["name"]

Comment: $new_data["name"] is also an Array. if you want to get object data, you have to make a new object. At first, you have to define Class to create your object.
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_oop_classes_objects.asp
You can find how to define class and make a object.